# "Are also" or "also are"

Tags: grammar

I'm making a birthday card for my British dad who's living in Germany and is going to get hit hard by brexit.

> Expats also are migrants

Or

> Expats are also migrants

I tried to research it but the answer I found is that depending on context both versions could be correct. Now I'm not sure which one to use. In my opinion the first one looks better but I'd like to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Clearer would be to say "Expats, *too*, are ..."

Comment: At least we have not seen the horror that is "ex-pat".

Comment: I wouldn't let a little hyphen frighten me :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what your emphasis is, but it is a matter of opinion.

If you write 'migrants also are...' you emphasize the ALSO, like retorting an argument where someone has missed that point.

If you write 'migrants are also...' then the emphasis on ALSO is weakened.

I personally would write like this: 'expats are migrants too'. I dropped 'fucking' because I feel it jumbles up the meaning, not because I think it is offense or something silly like that.

Comment: Offence at (or just impatience with) needless sexual profanity is not "silly" to many people.